# get duplicated value in records

Tags: sql, mysql

i have some records in a table. some of them have duplicated value in a field.
i want to extract these duplicated values with mysql commands.
how can  i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like: I have a Person table, and there are multiple person with the same name, I want to find them?

You can do that using a group by clause:

```
select p.name, count(p.name) c 
from person p 
group by p.name 
having count(p.name) > 1
```

If you want to check duplicate multiple columns, then add all of them to the `select` and `group by`

```
select p.name, p.age, p.sex, count(*) c 
from person p 
group by p.name, p.age, p.sex 
having count(*) > 1
```